# Should an AngularJS controller handle the business logic or the presentation logic?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

In the AngularJS documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller it says:

- Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.

Now, in the book I'm reading (AngularJS Up and Running O'Reily), which is a highly recommended book for learning AngularJS, it says (on page 17):

- Some of the more common responsibilities of a controller in an AngularJS application include:

  - Presentation logic, such as how to display elements, which parts of the UI to show, how to style them, etc.

Isn't this exactly what the documentation not to use controllers for? What's recommended? (is it recommended that the controller handles the business or the presentation logic?).

Answer (score 1):

Both can be handled using Angular JS, presentation layer and business logic layer. Suppose you have to point any action to UI with respect to run time changes that would be checked - business logic layer.

Suppose I have to upload a image/file now using angular's module I'll take the image/file and then it'll be sent for upload to server - let's say node js server- now angular can receive timely updates about upload progress and that would be shown on the presentation layer.

If you need more clarification please let me know.

Comment: right, but what's recommended? The AngularJS Up and Running book says that the responsibilities of a controller in an AngularJS application is to handle presentation logic. The documentations say exactly to Not do that and say that the controllers should only contain business logic.

Comment: Exactly what the documentation says, just use it to trigger presentation layers. It is just used to trigger presentation layer not entirely handle it. The magic in the end will be shown on the main page.

Comment: @user18703 Hey if the answer is acceptable for you please accept it man if not let me help you.